# jQueryUI Sortable Change event fires multiple times on single change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

link to jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k8wYF/1/  (working)

```
var count;
$("#sortable").sortable({
    start : function(){
               count = 0;
            },
    change : function(){
                 count++;                
            },
    stop : function(){
                 alert(count);          
            }
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();​
```

on single change

```
count : 1
```

but, i want to refresh sortable on sortableStart

link to jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k8wYF/   (not working)

```
var count;
$("#sortable").sortable({
    start : function(){
               $("#sortable").sortable("refresh");       //refresh sortable
               count = 0;
            },
    change : function(){
                 count++;                
            },
    stop : function(){
                 alert(count);          
            }
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();​
```

then, on single change

```
count : 16  (multiple times)
```

Comment: buddy both fiddle have same script

Comment: Start seems to be being called on the mouse moveevent when you are dragging an element. The question I have is why do you have to refresh on start ?

Comment: in second fiddle , i was addded line $("#sortable").sortable("refresh");

Comment: @SaintGerbil Because, i want to hide some list items on sortable start and show on stop.. for multiple moves on single change

Comment: @Arrayoutofbound: Hiding list items will trigger the change for each item changing positions in the DOM, when the list is refreshed. Your current code only shows `count++` if you can post the actual code you want to execute on `change` and how it is effected causing incorrect result it will be easier to analyse and help you in finding a solution on where to put which code.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Thank u... i will update code soon.. multiple trigger events not affect my result but performance issue. i cant minimize code in onChange event so.. i can add validation on change event before onChange code executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [**docs**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

**Change**

> This event is triggered during sorting, but only when the DOM position
>   has changed.

**Refresh**

> Refresh the sortable items. Custom trigger the reloading of all
>   sortable items, causing new items to be recognized.

What you are experiencing is normal. When refreshing, all items are moved into the expected positions, altering the DOM, thus triggering the changed event each time.

If you want to add code to the change event, make sure it is code you want to execute at each change.

If you want to add code to only execute when sorting is finished, add it to either `stop` or `update`.

**Update**

> This event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM
>   position has changed.

**Stop**

> This event is triggered when sorting has stopped.

Depending on what your code will do, make sure you add it to the appropriate event.

Comment: i want to add code to the change event which execute at each change. and i want to hide some list on sortable start.

Answer (score 2):

Change appears to fire every time an element changes, so you're getting an increment with each moved li within the list. I switched it to update and took out the refresh and it seems to give the right count.

```
var count = 0;

$("#sortable").sortable({
    stop : function(){
                 alert(count);          
    },
    update : function(){
                 count++;  
    }
});

$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

You can also put the refresh back in, just don't reset your count to 0 each time and it seems to keep track well enough. Though, without more info on what you want, I can't really help much more.

Comment: You can do that, you just probably don't want the counter incremented on change, as it will give you the unexpected/undesirable results you saw before. You can still do something based on the count on change, though.

Comment: counter is just for demo only, my problem is change event fires multiple times,, http://jsfiddle.net/k8wYF/20/ just hold down one item and slightly move it position . then u get unexpected count in console. check it out

Comment: That's the expected functionality of change. If you want to fire something 1 time for each modification to the list as a whole, that's what update is designed for. If you have more sample code to indicate what you're trying to accomplish, we can probably be of more assistance.

Comment: Update event  is triggered when the user stopped sorting not on during sorting.. so its not works for me. because it not fires on every DOM position change..

Comment: example here,  http://aseptik.net/demo/jquery-sortable-change-event-element-position/

Comment: If you want it to fire on every DOM position change, use change, but then it's going to fire multiple times as items re-order, hence your count in that instance being based on things shifting around, rather than the overall update. It's a case of cake and eat it too, you may need to re-think how you're approaching the problem. But without a better code example, we're somewhat at an impasse.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16943/discussion-between-array-out-of-bound-and-tannerjs)